# How to fix the geometry error: \paperwidth too short when using the savetrees package with sig-alternate

Tags: geometry, savetrees

I am trying to use the savetrees package with the sig-alternate class but I am receiving the following error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.

See the geometry package documentation for explanation.
```

Comment: Please, add a minimal code exemplifying your problem so we can copy/paste it.

Comment: presumably that class does not set \paperwidth so geometry does not know the original size to set margins. But why use a journal-specific class and then change the layout? If you are not submitting to a journal that requires that class, why not use a generic class, and if you are submitting to such a journal they won't accept a changed page size.

Comment: Note that `sig-alternate` is a very badly written class; use it *only* if you're forced to, for a submission requiring it.

Comment: @egreg Would you recommend instead the original format of the ACM SIG style? See http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is a good point. I suppose that I was not interested in change the paper size but rather the spacing between items in descriptions and itemizations, etc.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian I would recommend *none* of the ACM classes. If you *have* to use them for a submission, don't try to modify their behavior, because the copy editor won't be happy. If it's for personal use, choose a different class.